# Yarn High Availability: ZKResourceManagerStateStore not found

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to set up Yarn to run in the HA configuration on Hadoop 2.7.3. When starting I receive the following error in the resource manager log file:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.ZKResourceManagerStateStore not found

My yarn-site.xml is bellow:

```
<configuration>
<!-- Resource Manager Configs -->
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.connect.retry-interval.ms</name>
    <value>2000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.automatic-failover.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.automatic-failover.embedded</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.cluster-id</name>
    <value>yarn-cluster</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.rm-ids</name>
    <value>rm1,rm2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.id</name>
    <value>rm1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.recovery.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.store.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.ZKResourceManagerStateStore</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.zk-address</name>
    <value>master:2181,slave1:2181,slave2:2181</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.scheduler.connection.wait.interval-ms</name>
    <value>5000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.work-preserving-recovery.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <!-- ResourceManager1 configs -->
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address.rm1</name>
    <value>master:23140</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address.rm1</name>
    <value>master:23130</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.https.address.rm1</name>
    <value>master:23189</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address.rm1</name>
    <value>master:23188</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address.rm1</name>
    <value>master:23125</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address.rm1</name>
    <value>master:23141</value>
  </property>

  <!-- ResourceManager2 configs -->
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address.rm2</name>
    <value>slave1:23140</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address.rm2</name>
    <value>slave1:23130</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.https.address.rm2</name>
    <value>slave1:23189</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address.rm2</name>
    <value>slave1:23188</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address.rm2</name>
    <value>slave1:23125</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address.rm2</name>
    <value>slave1:23141</value>
  </property>

<!-- Node Manager Configs -->
  <property>
    <description>Address where the localizer IPC is.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.localizer.address</name>
    <value>master:23344</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <description>NM Webapp address.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.webapp.address</name>
    <value>master:23999</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
    <value>/tmp/pseudo-dist/yarn/local</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
    <value>/tmp/pseudo-dist/yarn/log</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.shuffle.port</name>
    <value>23080</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.work-preserving-recovery.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
    <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.store.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.ZKResourceManagerStateStore</value>
  </property>
```

with

```
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.store.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.ZKRMStateStore</value>
  </property>
```

in yarn-site.xml and try again

Comment: That looks like it did it! Thank you, I've been staring at that for hours. I have been using https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-2-x/topics/cdh_hag_rm_ha_config.html as a reference. Is this doc out of date?

Comment: in that doc i see value of yarn.resourcemanager.store.class as org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.ZKRMStateStore. from where did you get the yarn-site.xml?

Comment: ZKResourceManagerStateStore is the recommended value in the config description above. I see that it conflicts with the example.

Comment: it might be so or they will be using cdh-yarn jars because i am not seeing in https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/branch-2.7.3/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/resourcemanager/recovery